# How to add up row totals in report viewer

Tags: rdlc, report-viewer2010

I'm new to reporting and the jargon that goes with so I will try to draw it insted of write it.

```
|         |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
-------------------------------------------------
| Apples  |   1   |   3   |   6   |   2   |  12   |
-------------------------------------------------
| Oranges |   3   |   2   |   4   |   1   |  10   |
-------------------------------------------------
| Bananas |   5   |   3   |       |   1   |   9   |
-------------------------------------------------
|         |       |       |       |       |  31   |
```

I need to sum up the last column `E` where I indicated `31`. The cells with values `12`,`10`,`9` are obtained by `=Sum(Fields!A.Value + Fields!B.Value + Fields!C.Value + Fields!D.Value)`.

I can't change the sql query and/or the dataset that is used. Does any one have a suggestion? Thanks!

EDIT:
I've added a function to the code

```
Public Total_lookup_Sum As Integer = 0 

Public Function Lookup_Sum(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer

  Total_lookup_Sum = Total_lookup_Sum + value     

  Return Total_lookup_Sum 

End Function
```

and calling like this `Code.Equals(ReportItems!txtFruitTotal.Value)` but I get `FALSE`.

Comment: Why doesn't =Sum(Fields!E.Value) suffice?

Comment: Because `12`, `10`, `9` are sums of A+B+C+D and I get an error `The Value expression for the text box ‘lblGrandTotal’ refers to the field ‘lblInterimTotals’. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.
`

Comment: Have you tried looking into using the aggregate function(s)?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a3517a3b-16d6-4b1d-9201-afcdd949dfdc

Comment: @Shelby115: See my edits, I did try a function.

Comment: @Hardik, this is what I get: `The Value expression for the textrun 'lblGrandTotal.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an aggregate function (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another aggregate function (or RunningValue). Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions.
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a help of a colleague the answer was reached:

```
Sum(Fields!A.Value) + Sum(Fields!B.Value)  + Sum(Fields!C.Value) + Sum(Fields!D.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Cell Where 31 is simply, make this Expression

```
=Sum(Fields!A.Value) + Sum(Fields!B.Value)  + Sum(Fields!C.Value) + Sum(Fields!D.Value)

OR 

=Sum(Fields!E.Value)
```