# C# Replacement String

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

Hi To All Good Programmers,

I am developing a web-based app in which I need to generate some kind of reports. To do that, I prefer to use .rdlc embedded in VS 2010. There is a report named 'AccountReport' in which table rows are grouped according to some field of the table and it works fine.

**The Problem:** I need to add the Sum of a column as the last record of each group, the Sum is not a field of database table.. So How can I group it?

Here is a snap shot of what I need as the result. I have it already except the last record(row).

[image: Report Image]

How Can I rich the 'Total' Record? It is grouped by the 'Current Asset'. This image is prepared using MS Word of course.

Any Idea pleas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add up row totals in report viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449548/how-to-add-up-row-totals-in-report-viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Sum Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252113(v=vs.90).aspx) of Visual Studio Report Designer. Add a row in your report to show the total. Use the SUM function with your desired columnn name to set the expression. Check this answer for step by step pictorial details [Sum of Column Values in rdlc report](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/sum-of-a-column-values-in-reports-automatically-using-expres/). 
See similar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a3517a3b-16d6-4b1d-9201-afcdd949dfdc/calculating-total-of-an-expression-column)